# Create big zip archive in PHP

Tags: php, stream, zip, on-the-fly

In a current PHP project, I need to bundle up a bunch of PDF files in some sort of archive so the user can download them all together. Because zip is most common and even the most basic non-IT-Windows guys know about it, I was going for a zip archive.

My code looks like the following

```
$invoices = getRequestedInvoices(); // load all requested invoices, this function is just for demonstration

// Create a temporary zip archive
$filename = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($filename, \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

foreach($invoices as $invoice)
{
    // create the pdf file and add it to the archive
    $pdf = new InvoicePdf($invoice); // this is derived from \ZendPdf\PdfDocument
    $zip->addFromString($pdf->getFilename(), $pdf->render()); // for clarification: the getFilename method creates a filename for the PDF based on the invoice's id
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invoices.zip"');
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);
exit;
```

This script works fine if the server has enough memory. Unfortunately our productive system is very limited so the script only works with a few PDF files, but most of the time it runs out of memory and aborts. Adding unlink($pdf) at the end of the foreach loop didn't help, so my guess is the ZipArchive object is using up the memory.

I am trying to add as little dependencies as possible to the project, so I would love to be able to solve this with PHPs (PHP 5.4) own functions or functions from Zend Framework 2. I was looking for some way of directly streaming the archive (the zip:// stream wrapper looked good at first, but it's read-only), but that seems to be impossible with zip archives.

Does anyone have an idea? Maybe a different but also widely known type of archive that allows streaming? Compression is not a must

Comment: if you're memory constrained, then don't use the built-in zip stuff. You can do `exec("zip $filename file1 file2 file3")` instead, which won't be subject to PHP's memory limits. You'll have to be very careful with the various filenames to prevent shell injection attacks, but it would give you your zip without killing PHP with an out-of-memory error.

Comment: i thought about that but is that way platform independent? i need to keep the future in mind when we might migrate to a different server (with unknown properties)

Comment: not really. once you start dealing with the shell, you're basically platform dependent anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find a quick solution to this problem, so despite trying to avoid it, I had to use an external dependency.

I found the ZipStream class from the PHPZip project (https://github.com/Grandt/PHPZip) which does the job just fine.

```
$zip = new \ZipStream("invoices.zip");

foreach($invoices as $invoice)
{
    $pdf = new InvoicePdf($invoice);
    $zip->addFile($pdf->render(), $pdf->getFilename());
}

$zip->finalize();
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native `ZipArchive::addFile()` instead of `addFromString()`. It is not memory consuming. But PDF invoice has to be saved into a file and such file must exist during `ZipArchive::close()` and deleted after it. Something like:

```php
<?php

...

$toDelete = [];
foreach($invoices as $invoice)
{
    // create the pdf file and save it as temporary
    $pdf = new InvoicePdf($invoice);
    $toDelete[] = $pdfFile = tempnam('tmp', 'pdf');
    file_put_contents($pdfFile, $pdf->render());

    // add invoice into archive
    $zip->addFile($pdfFile, $pdf->getFilename());
}

$zip->close();
array_walk($toDelete, 'unlink');

...
```